# With or without 'this' in POO attribute class

Tags: c++, class, this

I wonder if there is some reason or not to use `this` in a attribute class?

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        int m_foo;

    public:
        int getIntance() { return this->m_foo; }
}
```

Other than the fact its say that this is the current class, are there others reasons?

Comment: That `this` is implicit I guess !

Comment: Java / C++ ? You tagged both languages.

Comment: How does it relate to java tag?

Comment: you are returning an int but your return type is Foo. How is that possible? Moreover to the question, it does not make any difference if you left that this. Because, it is implicit.

Comment: Woops , the method return an int !

Answer (score 1):

No, do not use it. In that particular case, it is not needed, and this is less typing :

```
int getIntance() { return m_foo; }
```

Less you write is better. Even for people reading you code (they'll have less to read)

Comment: `m_foo` is an `int` but the method returns a `Foo`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, the question is weird. I agree

Comment: Woops , the method return an int ! sorry !

Answer (score 1):

`this` is less typing. It is not mandatory in this particular case. There is no reason to use `this` keyword unless if you want to pass the current instance of your object to a function for example.

You can simply write :

```
int getIntance() { return m_foo; }
```

It is weird to call a method `getInstance` to return an `int`. It is quite uncommon...

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use `this`, except when, for example, you want something outside the class to point to your instance (let's say, you add your instance - `this` - to a list of pointers).

In your example, `this` is redundant, since `m_foo` could easily have been returned by `return m_foo;` without any problem.

However, `this` can only be used in **non-static member functions**, or else it won't compile.